# Understanding Oracle Transactions

Tags: oracle, transactions

I am trying to get my head around Oracle transactions, and I’m getting some confusing information.

I am used to a DBMS where you would create a transaction with something like this:

```sql
--  do something

START TRANSACTION;
--  do things
--  do more things
COMMIT;
```

If something goes wrong, then the transaction is rolled back. However what goes on before the transaction is committed.

If I just want to test things I should be able to do this:

```sql
--  do something

START TRANSACTION;
--  do things
--  do more things
ROLLBACK;
```

Then only the first part should be committed.

I read that Oracle doesn’t have a specific `START TRANSACTION` statement. In that case how would I control what’s committed and what’s rolled back?

Comment: Oracle has `SET TRANSACTION`, which does what you ask for: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/cncpt/transactions.html#GUID-5BB15405-8A03-47DE-8A20-63E1B83E1361

Comment: In general, the "start transaction" is implicit, following each commit. A rollback would reset to the most recent committed state.

Comment: @pmdba So, effectively, if I start a group with `COMMIT;`, it’s like starting a new transaction?

Comment: @Manngo Oracle has transactions but you don't need to explicitly start them; the SQL engine will implicitly start a transaction with the first statement you execute and will implicitly close the transaction when you `COMMIT` (or when there is an error and the transaction is rolled back).

Comment: Unlike Postgres or MySQL that has `start transaction` statement Oracle doesn't have autocommit mode: you always have to explicitly issue the required statement to end a transaction - either `commit` or `rollback`. Each of these commands start new transaction unit. If you want to save your intermediate changes, you may use `savepoint` as described in the answer, but it doesn't persist changes for others and just allows you to rollback to it. Also note that each syntactically valid DDL statement performs an implicit commit at the very beginning and at the completion and it cannot be rolled back

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`SAVEPOINT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/cncpt/sql.html#GUID-73F24816-881A-4849-B8A7-EA9B446A24A7):

```sql
-- do first thing

SAVEPOINT your_savepoint_name;

-- do second thing

ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT your_savepoint_name;

-- do third thing

COMMIT;
```

Which would:

1. implicitly start a transaction;
2. do the first thing;
3. create a savepoint then do the second thing and then roll back to the savepoint reverting the changes done by that second thing (keeping the changes from the first thing, before the savepoint); and
4. do the third thing and commit the transaction (with the changes from the first and third things).